# How do I pass the button id when using a script

Tags: javascript, html

I have a modal with a form.

```
<form id="timesheetform" action="code.php" method="POST">
```

The form has the button of type=submit and name="inserttimesheetrecord".

```
<button type="submit" style="float: left;" name="inserttimesheetrecord"  id="inserttimesheetrecord" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" >Submit</button>
```

The code to insert the record into a database table is stored in separate php file called code.php.

This was working fine.

Then I added a script to check the validity of the data. As a result the submit button's id "inserttimesheetrecord" no longer passes to code.php

The code for this is:

```
document.getElementById("timesheetform").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
// Prevent the form from submitting by default
event.preventDefault();

// Check if all required fields are filled
const date = document.getElementById('date').value;
const hours = document.getElementById('hours').value;
const ordernumber = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
const ordertype = document.getElementById('orderType').value;
const steptask = document.getElementById('StepTaskInput').value;
const notes = document.getElementById('notes').value;
    
const validationMessage = document.getElementById('validationMessage');

console.log(hours);

let missingFields = [];

if (!date) {
    // Need to change this to check the date is within 14 days.
    missingFields.push('date');
}
if (!hours || hours<=0) {
    missingFields.push('hours');
}
if (!ordernumber) {
    missingFields.push('ordernumber');
}
if (ordertype=='Non-Charge' && !notes) {
    missingFields.push('notes');
}
if (ordertype!='Non-Charge' && !steptask) {
    missingFields.push('StepTaskInput');
}
if (missingFields.length > 0) {
    validationMessage.innerHTML = `Please fill in the following fields: ${missingFields.join(', ')}.`;
} else {
    validationMessage.innerHTML = ''; // Clear any previous validation message
    // If all fields are filled, submit the form
    this.submit();
    //document.getElementById("timesheetform").submit();
}

});
```

In addition to `this.submit();` I also tried `document.getElementById("timesheetform").submit();` but neither passed the id which means `if(isset($_POST['inserttimesheetrecord']))` does return tree and process the record.

How do I 'pass' the submit button name to code.php when using a script?

Comment: Using the `submit` method of the form means no submit button parameter will be added (because you are _not_ submitting the form via that button any more.) You can either move the `event.preventDefault();` into the final `if` where you determined that this should _not_ be allowed to submit now (and leave out the `else` branch completely); or you will have to add a hidden field of the same name to your form, so that the parameter will get created. (That hidden fields then only needs to be enabled, when you actually want to send that parameter.)

Comment: Thanks. I think I can work with that.

Comment: That resolved the issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to allow the default processing to occur if things are valid. Like:

```
document.getElementById("timesheetform").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {

    // Check if all required fields are filled
    const date = document.getElementById('date').value;
    const hours = document.getElementById('hours').value;
    const ordernumber = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
    const ordertype = document.getElementById('orderType').value;
    const steptask = document.getElementById('StepTaskInput').value;
    const notes = document.getElementById('notes').value;
    
    const validationMessage = document.getElementById('validationMessage');

    console.log(hours);

    let missingFields = [];

    if (!date) {
        // Need to change this to check the date is within 14 days.
        missingFields.push('date');
    }
    if (!hours || hours<=0) {
        missingFields.push('hours');
    }
    if (!ordernumber) {
        missingFields.push('ordernumber');
    }
    if (ordertype=='Non-Charge' && !notes) {
        missingFields.push('notes');
    }
    if (ordertype!='Non-Charge' && !steptask) {
        missingFields.push('StepTaskInput');
    }
    if (missingFields.length > 0) {
        // Prevent the form from submitting by default
        event.preventDefault();
        validationMessage.innerHTML = `Please fill in the following fields: ${missingFields.join(', ')}.`;
    }

});
```

Comment: That resolved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer helped you solve the issue, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the submit event for validating the form you can let the build in validation do it for you. Here I have added attributes to the different form field to validate against. And a title attribute for displaying help to the user when the mouse hover the input.

Use the invalid event for reporting back to the user. If everything is ok the form will submit. I changed the name of the button to "record" and added a value attribute to the button -- not important, but could make more sense on the backend.

BTW: When you submit a form using JavaScript use [requestSubmit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit) and parse the button as parameter insted of using `submit()`. Something like: `document.forms.timesheetform.requestSubmit(document.forms.timesheetform.record)` in the case of the following example.

```js
const validationMessage = document.getElementById('validationMessage');

document.forms.timesheetform.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.target.classList.add('invalid');
}, true);

document.forms.timesheetform.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let invalid = [...form.elements].filter(elm => !elm.validity.valid && !elm.disabled);
  if (invalid.length > 0) {
    validationMessage.textContent = 'Please fill in the following fields: ' + invalid.map(elm => elm.name).join(', ');
  }
}, true);

// this third event listener is just for preventing the default
// error message from showing up.
document.forms.timesheetform.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
}, true);

document.forms.timesheetform.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  if (e.target.validity.valid) {
    e.target.classList.remove('invalid');
  }
  validationMessage.textContent = '';
});

document.forms.timesheetform.ordertype.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  form.notes.disabled = (e.target.value == 'noncharge') ? false : true;
  form.steptask.disabled = (e.target.value != 'noncharge') ? false : true;
}, true);
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: .3em;
}

.invalid:not(:disabled) {
  border: solid red 2px;
}
```

```html
<form name="timesheetform" action="code.php" method="POST">
  <label>Date<input type="date" name="date" required></label>
  <label>Hours<input type="number" min="1" max="12" name="hours" required title="Number between 1 and 12"></label>
  <label>Order number<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]{5}" name="ordernumber" required title="5 digit number"></label>
  <label>Order type<select name="ordertype" required>
  <option value="1">Type 1</option>
  <option value="noncharge">Non-Charge</option></select></label>
  <label>Step task<input type="text" minlength="1" name="steptask" required title="Minimum 12 characters"></label>
  <label>Notes<textarea name="notes" minlength="1" required disabled title="Minimum 12 characters"></textarea></label>
  <button type="submit" name="record" value="inserttimesheet" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Submit</button>
</form>
<p id="validationMessage"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you Chrwahl for the alternative solution. In the case of my timesheet, the validation isn't just a matter of whether the forms are filled in. In certain cases as long as the right combination is filled in then it is valid, so I don't think I can use the built-in validation in this case. I will also look up the requestsubmit() function.

Comment: @SimonKing ups, I didn't notice the condition on the notes/steptask. You could solve that enabling/disabling the notes and the stedtask form field depending on the selection in ordertype. I added that to my answer example.